# Fitting Multiple Logistic Regression with Interaction between Quantitative and Qualitative Explanatory Variables with drm function from drc package

Tags: r, glm, logistic-regression, drc

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36065327/707145) answered by @EDi. I wonder how to fit the following `glm` model with `drc` function from `drc` package.

**GLM Code**

```
Type  <- rep(x=LETTERS[1:3], each=5, times=2)
Conc  <- rep(rep(x=seq(from=0, to=40, by=10), times=3), 2)
Rep   <- factor(rep(x=1:2, each=15))
Total <- 50
Kill  <- c(
            10, 30, 40, 45, 38, 5, 25, 35, 40, 32, 0, 32, 38, 47, 40,
            11, 33, 38, 43, 36, 4, 23, 34, 42, 34, 2, 35, 39, 46, 42
            )

df <- data.frame(Type, Conc, Rep, Total, Kill)

fm1 <- 
  glm(
    formula = Kill/Total~Rep+Type*Conc
    , family  = binomial(link="logit")
    , data    = df
    , weights = Total
  )

summary(fm1)
summary(fm1)$coef
anova(object=fm1, test="LRT")
```

**drc Code**

```
library(drc)
fm2 <- drm(Kill/Total ~ Rep+Conc, 
           curveid = Type, 
           weights = Total, 
           data    = df, 
           fct     =  L.4(fixed = c(NA, 0, 1, NA)), 
           type    = 'binomial'
           )

summary(fm2)
```

I think `drm` code also includes the interaction between `Rep` and `Type` which is not required.

Comment: I don't think that `drc` is building a GLM. I think you need to use `nls` if you want to replicate those results.

Comment: @42 DRC is building a GLM.

Comment: What is the basis for your belief? (I looked at the code. What did you do?)

Comment: My believe is based on answer to original question.

Comment: The degree of confusion on your part about the underlying mathematical and statistical methods is my reason for voting to close. I don't think there is a well-formed coding question here. You need to get advice from the statisticians at stats.stackexchange.com